# How to change the face of org-display-outline-path in echo area?

Tags: org-mode, echo-area, path, outline

In org-mode, I set all the outlines to be displayed in one face size (regardless of their hierarchy) by setting `(setq org-level-color-stars-only t)`.

However, when I select an outline, org-mode displays the outline path in the echo area (minibuffer) in different face sizes based on their hierarchy.

What I would like to achieve is to either 1) turn off displaying any outline path in the echo area, or 2) set the face of the path to be one size regardless of the outline hierarchy.

- macOS Sierra
- Spacemacs 0.200.9@25.1.1
- Org 9.0.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, I wrote the following function to achieve the first aim.

```
(defun override-org-level-faces ()
    (dolist (face '(org-level-1
                    org-level-2
                    org-level-3
                    org-level-4))
    (set-face-attribute face nil :weight 'normal
                                 :height 1.0
                                 :foreground (face-foreground 'default)
                                 :background (face-background 'default))))
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'override-org-level-faces)
```

This code will:

- prevent emacs from changing the height of org-level faces depending on their position in the outline's hierarchy
- match the colours of the faces with the ones in the current theme
- limit the hook to org-mode only

Answer (score 1):

An answer to the point : *turn off displaying any outline path in the echo area*.

Encountered the same problem : that behaviour appeared after changing the distribution from `org` to `org-plus-contrib` (from [orgmode.org](http://orgmode.org/elpa/) repository).

The under-the-point-headline-print-in-echo-area behaviour seems to come from `org-eldoc` which is activated via a hook in `org-mode-hook`.

Unfortunately, I did not find any customize variable to change that behaviour - the best solution I found was to completely remove the hook :

> (remove-hook 'org-mode-hook 'org-eldoc-load)